# How can I fix this matplotlib issue?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
y = np.array([3, 8, 1, 10])

plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

It doesn't show me the diagram! Only this text:

```
<BarContainer object of 4 artists>
```

This code is simple, so as to be more comprehensive. I was trying to visualize some data and jupyter did not show me the diagram. Then, I tried to run this simple code and it showed me this text, instead of a diagram. Can you help me please?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What environment are you running in? Have you tried hitting Alt+Tab to find the figure in the background?

Comment: Your code works fine for me from a command line.  Matplotlib should be able to detect Jupyter and put the output there.

Comment: I have tried to run it in jupyter and vs code.  Yesterday, I was able to run it, it's strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit strange because your code should work too. Maybe try this, see if the output is the same:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

x = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
y = np.array([3, 8, 1, 10])

ax.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I leave you a link to lots of useful [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_bar_plot.htm).

Comment: Now it worked, thank you! But I can't understand why my code wasn't able to work. It's strange because yesterday I was running the same code and it was working... Do you have any idea, what's the problem?

Comment: @GRG27 , Did you restart the kernel when you were having issues? Restart Jupyter? On the other hand, if it continues to work, I wouldn't sweat it too much. Sometimes during coding development you can clobber something or mess up the back-end handling plotting and not notice until much later. So it becomes hard to trace if you happened to remove the original cause. Look around for the 'hidden state' of Jupyter notebooks if you haven't come across that term yet. It's either that or you messed up the plotting back end before it stopped working that time.